# What is difference between git clone and git init?

Tags: git, pull

I am not completely able to understand the difference between both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `git init`, you can initialize and empty git repository in your local and using `git clone`, you can clone an existing git repository to your system.

I hope that helps!